# Will I need to re-authenticate all devices if I install AdvancedTomato on router and replace DD-WRT?

Tags: wireless-networking, installation, dd-wrt, authentication, tomato

I am in a bit of a pickle. I would like to install [AdvancedTomato](https://advancedtomato.com/) over my existing [DD-WRT](https://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) router firmware, but I am afraid I will have to re-authenticate all devices previously connected to DD-WRT. I have a lot of devices and some of them are hard to get to. If I install a new firmware on my router, will all devices need to re-authenticate even if I use the same SSID and password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the devices will not need to "reauthenticate". Provided the SSID remains the same and the password (and in some cases the encryption type) remains the same devices will continue to work.

This is common and having a common SSID and password allows seemlessly roaming between AP's on the same network.